# Shopware Twig Fiddle

Tags: twig, shopware6

I want to render a twig expression in https://shopware.foo/

```
{{ page.product.translated.description|raw|striptags|sw_sanitize|u.truncate(125, '…') }}
```

There is https://twigfiddle.com/ but it does ot support `sw_sanitize`.

How can I run the twig interpreter programatically.

I tried ([fiddle](https://shopware.foo/qBp2uu8t4x))

```
var_dump($container->getParameter('kernel.shopware_version'));


$loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader([
    'template.twig' => "Hello {{ name|raw|striptags|sw_sanitize|u.truncate(125, '…') }}!",
]);
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('template.twig', ['name' => '&nbsp;foo&nbsp;']);
```

But this does not load the `sw_sanitize` filter as well:

```
Unknown "sw_sanitize" filter in "template.twig" at line 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](https://shopware.foo/wsq2r4bXXY) works:

```
var_dump($container->getParameter('kernel.shopware_version'));

$twig = $container->get('twig');

$templateString = "Hello {{ name|raw|striptags|sw_sanitize|u.truncate(125, '…') }}!";
$template = $twig->createTemplate($templateString);

// Provide variables to the template
$variables = [
    'name' => '<ul><li>&nbsp;foo</li></ul>'
];

echo $template->render($variables);
```

(with a little bit of help from ChatGPT to be honest, but prompted and validated by a human)